Why is email filled in when not logged in, even for new visitor
I am the developer of the SpeakOut! WP plugin.  I have a user of the plugin that is seeing an email address pre-filled on a form.  Normally the answer to this is "Yes, because you are logged in as an administrator".
But this is different.  When I visited their site for the first time, not logged in or anything, I also see the address pre-filled.  I am waiting to confirm that it is also the administrator address...but what else could it be?
I have had a look in their site and there has been no modification to the code causing this to happen.  To be sure, I uploaded a fresh version of the script, it didn't help.
So the question:  How is this possible?  What could be injecting that email address?

I have been able to figure out what is causing the problem. I have disabled the “Limit Login Attempts Reloaded” plugin and automatically your “SpeakOut” plugin now works correctly. I believe they are sharing common variables. Therefore, it is important that in the features or possible incompatibilities, the compatibility issue with that plugin is indicated.
In addition to displaying the email address of the site's "administrator", it also affects other features of "SpeakOut" such as the petition signature counter.

browsers will prefill whatever infomation they can guess at forms. You can control it by using the autocomplete attribute on the form or specific input. You can use it to prevent the autofill, but if you actually want to control the data being set in the input it is more up to the browser (although I would assume that the main browsers behave identically at this point in time).
email address is probably something which browsers are more agressive about prefilling.
As for "Yes, because you are logged in as an administrator" - very unlikely although without seeing your code it is hard to say for sure.

Thanks for your answer, but how would autocomplete explain the form pre-filling the site administrator's email address when I have never visited the site before?

well, it wasn't clear in the question what is the email that being displayed. If it is of the site's admin it is a big security threat and the plugin that doing that should not be used any more

.... but as implied in my comment, there are many details that are missing in the question, so you get an hopefully usefull guess as an answer :)
